# Rails 6 merge hash to ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm wondering is it possible to merge hash into ActiveRecord object similar to SQL queries where you can manipulate data with e.g. `SUM(transfers.shares_number) as sold_shares`

Long story short if I've an user object:

```
=> #<User id: 201253217, email: "daren_hoppe@nicolas.name" >
```

is it possible to merge hash params: `params = { sold_shares: 123 }` to this User object in order to get:

```
=> #<User id: 201253217, email: "daren_hoppe@nicolas.name", sold_shares: 123>
```

Worth to mention that `sold_shares` is not a column in users table.

I've tried to use `user.merge(options)` but I'm getting `NoMethodError: undefined method merge!' for #<User`

Comment: Is a `Hash` with User attributes and the params `Hash` good enough for you? Or do you need an `ActiveRecord` instance with those attributes? Both are achievable

Comment: I need an `ActiveRecord` instance with this `sold_shares: 123` attribute

Comment: Is `sold_shares` already an attribute on a `User` that you only want to set? Or does a `User` currently not respond to `sold_shares`?

Comment: @spickermann it's not an attribute of anything

Comment: Is the list of key/values fixed in that hash? Or might there be more or other attributes in other param hashed?

Comment: @spickermann it's fixed

Comment: When you only need a user instance to return a value for the `sold_shares` in tests why don't you just stub that method? `user.stub(: sold_shares, 123)` might do the job.

Comment: It won't work in MiniTest - `NameError: undefined method sold_shares for class #<Class`

Answer (score 1):

I doubt merge exist on an ActiveRecord object but you can use the `assign_attributes` method.

```rb
user = User.find(...)
user.assign_attributes(params)
```

as long as `sold_shares` attribute writer is defined on `User`:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # you may wanna use an attr_accessor instead
  attr_writter :sold_shares
end
```

There is a couple of downsides, though:

- `attributes` and other serializing methods won't serialize `sold_shares`
- if you need more attributes, you will have to add it to your model

Comment: `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'sold_shares' for User` - I guess I would have to add it somehow in the model but I don't want to do that. I just want to get manipulated data identical to the data coming from the SQL query (I gave an example in the question)

Comment: you can define a attribute accessor on the User model, this will allow you to populate field which do not exist in the db as long as you don't try to save it

`attr_accessor : sold_shares`

Comment: I don't want to to this because I need it only for the MiniTest. In a real life `sold_shares` is passed to the object using SQL query (SUM .... as sold_shares) - this way he gets an active record object with added fields.

Comment: Well... I am not saying I'd do that, but... If you need this only for testing and you are pretty sure about what you are doing, why don't you do some monkey patching for the User class inside your minitest file? Again: I'm not saying this is ideal, but... It will work

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear *why* you're trying to merge aggregate attributes into your model, so your question is difficult to answer, but that's not normally the way things work in Rails.

The normal approach to get aggregate SQL functions is just to run the following code:

`user.transfers.sum(:shares_number)`

This assumes you have a `has_many :transfers` association on the `User` model.

There are similar methods for other SQL aggregate functions.

You can add a `sold_shares` method to the `User` model, which does this if you like, but that won't integrate into all of the ActiveRecord features necessarily, for example, it won't be in the `User#attributes` hash and won't appear in `inspect`/console output.

You can get arbitrarily tricky here fixing all that, but it is almost certainly unnecessary for what you actually need. Don't go against the grain unless you have to.

Alternatively you take the model's attributes and your extensions and merge them into a hash, something like `user.attributes.merge('my_field' => ...)`.

You could also create some kind of proxy object that implemented that. This is often a preferred approach where a model object becomes too complicated, but might be overkill here.

There is also the "counter cache" feature which does add an (automatically-managed) field to the database, and so will be fully-integrated into the attributes hash, but this is only for counting, not summing.